# how to connect a user to wifi network using predefined ssid and password in iOS

Tags: ios

I am going to develop an iOS app that has to search the list of nearby available wifi networks of our app community and has to connect with any one of it.Here all the wifi network's ssid and passwords are predefined. I had searched a lot in stack overflow all of them said it is not possible in IOS (doing with jailbreak will be rejected by apple). But those all questions are asked before more than one year.But i hope there may be any update on it at least i have to connect the user with that predefined ssid and password i should do it. thinking positively i am asking this question anyone can help me please. thanks in advance

Comment: ans : We can't do that

Comment: thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still NO. You cannot do that. There is a reason that your device has Settings app. You can use [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) framework to check if device is connected to wifi or not and you can let the user navigate to settings and connect wifi from there.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I could not understand the line"There is a reason that your device has Settings app" can you tell me what that means I am very new to IOS development @Teja Nandamuri

Comment: As far as I know, Appple takes so many security measures while connecting to a network. If apple exposes its API , then people might connect to unsafe networks which steal device data. So things like connecting to network has to be done via Settings app in iPhone.

Comment: thank you can we get any permission from apple team to do these things some one said me but don't know wright or wrong

Comment: No you cannot. You can start discussion thread on apple forums but you cannot request them. You can file a radar if you see any performance issue/bug in your app.